# How to handle .debug_info relocation R_X86_64_32 out of range: 4295935474 is not in [0, 429496729]

Tags: gcc, g++, ld, lld

I am building a cpp project, but the link fails, because the `.debug_info` segment is too large, exceeding `2^32-1`. Is there a tool to locate which part of the code has a larger `.debug_info` segment, or is there a way to remove this limitation?

compiler version:

```
g++ (GCC) 10.3.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

error:

```
ld.lld: error: thread.cc:(.debug_info+0x90A0): relocation R_X86_64_32 out of range: 4306390516 is not in [0, 4294967295]; consider recompiling with -fdebug-types-section to reduce size of debug sections
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `-mcmodel=medium` to your compiler flags.  This way it will not assume that symbols are addressable with 32-bit offsets, they can use the full 64-bit address space.

Answer (score 0):

### **Description**

We had a similar problem

```
ld: error: name.cpp:(.debug_info+0x1FC1C): relocation R_X86_64_32 out of range: 4295177414 is not in [0, 4294967295]; consider recompiling with -fdebug-types-section to reduce size of debug sections
ld: error: second_name.cpp:(.debug_aranges+0x6): relocation R_X86_64_32...
```

In our case it is due to an overflow section `.debug_info`. To check this, you can try reducing the size of your code until it starts to build and use the `readelf` - utility. If you see that the section size is close to `0xfffffffffff`, then you have the same problem

### **Possible solutions**

[This](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) lists all the debug options available in gcc

1. You can try changing the DWARF format from 32 to 64. Note that this may greatly increase the size of the original file (see -gdwarf64)
2. It is also possible to divide the section into several parts (see -gsplit-dwarf)

You may also find the information from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DebugFission) helpful.